# Narrow down the return result based on a property value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say that I have a type like this

```
type Result = {error:true,response: undefined} | {error:undefined, response:{nick:string}}
```

This type should either return `error` prop and if there is no `error` then there is a `response`.

Now I'm trying to create a function that will process this `result` and narrow it down.

```
function unwrapResult<T extends {error: any}>(result:T) {
  if(result.error){
    throw result.error
  }
  return result
}
```

However, this function does not work as expected.

```
function test():Result {

  return {error:undefined,response:{nick:'iki'}}
}

const data = unwrapResult(test())
 
 data.response?.nick // response is {nick:string} | undefined

if(!data.error){
  data.response.nick // this is ok 
}
```

Is there a way to `unwrap` the result so that I'm left with `{response:{nick:string}}` so I don't have to have the `if(!data.error)` check which defeats the purpose of the `unwrapResult` function.

---

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvCAnXA9rgFzC6IQA0uCYBAdvBMVIvQCYQBmAlvROwC+AH2x5CJNp1792lKDXh1GzLPR4BjANbF4ZPgHNBggFAmubDcB4NW9AO64AhmDhJUAHgAqUCAA9gCA54MXwiYid6EEEAPgAKRRRgYi8ASmwTKCgeLgSEJIA6cSJUrEysqGAAC0J7BXzUIrDcctMsmmBEXHp692ATU3NLa1tAvTjU4jckjPKOrp6cZuIpbj4BaloGJmI1TR0Ach4tHgPjAbMNbbR2J2AnDDtHF2nUOLHgCdTMzNv7gsUyiYAH4CuptGYcnEAIR-JxNCSlcpwgFbFRg-YXIA)

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NDG68w) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example code to demonstrate the failing use cases.  Let me know.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Can you please explain what is going on there with the `Extract` type?  Also, is there a way to remove the `error` property completely?

Comment: I'll explain in the answer. "Also, is there a way to remove the `error` property completely?" I don't quite get what you're asking but this sounds like a separate followup question.  If you have a [mre] of what you want to see happen and what doesn't work I might be able to make a suggestion, but the comments are not a great place for that.  If I'm wrong and it's not a followup question but a small part of your existing question then you might want to [edit] to show it.

Comment: When I do `data.[property]`  I get correct code hints for the properties on the `data` object, but I also get `error: undefined` which is correct but I would just prefer that `error` property is completely removed from the `data` result`. Something like `Omit<typeof data, 'error'>`

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd46yN)?  It kind of seems out of scope of the original question.  Can we just stop talking about this and I can work on writing the answer to your question as asked when I get a chance?  Or do you want to edit the question to focus on this topic instead?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, error can only be true or undefined, not an actual Error object or undefined. That means that you don't need a generic parameter therefore fixing your problem.

```js
type Result = {
  error: true,
  response: undefined
} | {
  error: undefined,
  response: {
    nick: string
  }
}

function unwrapResult(result: Result) {
  if(result.error){
    throw result.error
  }

  return result
}

function test(): Result {

  return { error: undefined, response: { nick:'iki' } }
}

const data = unwrapResult(test())
 
data.response.nick

if(!data.error){
  data.response.nick
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFKEAToQPaEBcUwhiEANHlIQmCQHbwSWJsAmEAMwCWbCLxwBfKAB9sjIqQpQe-YaN4N8zeKw5c5%20fGyEBjANaV41EQHNGEyThwCeJ4EPbK2Ad0IBDMDgkVAAKbRRgSiCIgEoDKCEBMIQIgDoFMhjcQyoAC1JvJhTUdOIyeyctCGBEQjYi4OBHZ1d3T2AEYBCYqOK0XEZmGrrsAjKlFUERMToG3U5KLChjc3IAciEzITWoKQcHHBN2KyheP2A-DC9fAOjQjqtumLwcM4vU7XmIVJWzJ0SQgBCN5%20UqKLKMEEfFjHb6-SRAA)